# proving a space is a topological space

Tags: general-topology

In terms of Zariski Topology, how would I go about proving $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a topological space?

Would that imply showing that the empty set and the whole set are closed, a finite intersection is closed, and a union of arbitrary family of closed sets is open?

Comment: You could either show that the Zariski-closed sets satisfy the conditions to be a family of closed sets, or show that their complements satisfy the conditions to be a family of open sets.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that something is a topological space, you do need to show that the empty set and the whole set are open, finite intersections of open sets are open (and in the space), and similarly for arbitrary unions of open sets.

Using DeMorgan's Laws, $(\cup_{\alpha \in A} E_{a})^c = \cap_{\alpha \in A} E^c_{a}$ and $(\cap_{\alpha \in A} E_{a})^c = \cup_{\alpha \in A} E^c_{a}$, you can see that this is equivalent to finding that: empty set and whole set are open, infinite intersections of closed sets are closed, and finite unions of closed sets are closed. So the finite and arbitrary condition switch places.

Comment: With that in mind, would it be possible to show me that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a topological space while in zariski topology? It would be nice to just see.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write out an edit for this, but here is a reference that should have you on your way. Look especially at the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~carrell/423.pdf

Comment: That makes complete sense to me. Its a nice reference too. Is this the actual proof that $\mathbb{R}^2$ under zariski topology is a topological space?

Comment: it is, but a bit more general as you can see. What you should convince yourself is that the proof given shows that the empty set and whole set are closed, finite unions are closed, etc. But this is essentially trivial given the things in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of a Topology to prove the following:
A). The empty set and $X$ are in $T$.
B). The intersection of any finite collection of subsets of $X$ in $T$ is also in $T$. 
C). The union of any collection of sets in $T$ is also in $T$.

I. Prove the following:

1. Let $T$ and $S$ be topologies in $X$. Show that $S ∩T$ is also a topology in $X$.
2. Let $T=[U⊆ℝ: U = ∅\text{ or }U=ℝ\text{ or }U=(−∞,a) \text{ for some }a ∈ ℝ]$. Prove that $T$ is a topology on $ℝ$ (set of real numbers).